Email is not being sent on GoDaddy server but works on localhost
So, my laravel website can send the emails on localhost with same configuration but once I deployed the changes it can't send the email and here are the logs;
Connection could not be established with host "smtp.office365.com:587": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to smtp.office365.com:587 (Connection timed out)

I have tried to use 465, ssl and 587,tls... I also tried to use port 25 for office365.
I am using godaddy and asked their CS and they said they need to update my DNS and now I am waiting for that but I am not sure this will solve my problem.
However, when I go to config/mail.php, and replace transport => "smtp" to transport => "mail" it works out but the mail sending speed is very slow as compared to my localhost speed which I am doing through transport smtp.
My .env config:
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@website.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=passowr/
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@website.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="SiteName"

Mailer config: /config/mail.php:

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
            'verify_peer' => false,
        ],
        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs -i'),
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],

        'failover' => [
            'transport' => 'failover',
            'mailers' => [
                'smtp',
                'log',
            ],
        ],
     ]

